# How to skip API gateway redirect Spring security

Tags: java, spring-security, saml, netflix-eureka

Spring security makes a redirect from api gateway to the app, I want to skip the redirect as my idp can only authenticate the controller requestmapping path. 
For example, I only have authentication for foo.com/test but after login, spring security redirects to host:port/test, which is giving a  403 error.